# Apps won’t restore from backup

Tags: apple-store, iphone

I backed up my iPhone 5s, and when I try to restore my new iPhone 6s from that same backup, the apps won’t transfer over. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me and my iPhone 5S yesterday when I tried to restore that backup onto my iPhone 6S. You just have to install all of the apps again from the App Store. They will function just as you left them, will all game saves and app data in place, as all your app data was restored, just not the apps themselves.